# Vector derivative of expression involving square root

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How do I differentiate $\sqrt{\mathbf{x}^TM\mathbf{x}}$ with respect to vector $\mathbf{x}$ when $M$ is a symmetric matrix?

I guess that some generalization of the chain rule could be used, but I do not know how. I have managed to show that the derivative of $\mathbf{x}^TM\mathbf{x}$ with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ is $(M+M^T)\mathbf{x}$ but I do not know how to continue.

Comment: Did you tried the Gateaux derivative along $x$? The result follows from the definition.

Comment: This is basically the directional derivative in more general Banach spaces. The chain rule works of course.

Comment: Consider a scalar $\phi$ such that $\phi^2 = x^TMx$. You already know the derivative of the RHS and you want to find an expression for $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}$, should be simple.